# Как можно убрать событие при клике на input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Сейчас при клике на инпут срабатывает ajax событие, а мне надо что бы срабатывало, после ввода в инпут кол-ва товара!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(document).on('click change submit','[data-action]',function(){
        var action = $(this).attr('data-action');
  var cardClose = this.getAttribute("data-cardClose");
        var $this = $(this);
        var data = {};
        data['action'] = action;
        switch (action){
            case 'updatebasket':
                data['id'] = $this.attr('data-id');
                data['quantity'] = $('.dds_basket_quantity-'+data['id']).val();
                break;
            case 'delete':
                data['id'] = $this.attr('data-id');
                break;
        }
```

```css
/* added */
.goodsOrderItemsWrap {
  width: 97%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px; }
  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    .goodsOrderItemsWrap {
      margin-bottom: 40px; } }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .goodsOrderItemsWrap {
      margin-bottom: 40px; } }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .goodsOrderItemsWrap {
      margin-top: 25px;
      margin-bottom: 60px; } }

.goodsOrderList {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }
  .goodsOrderList li {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 2px; }
    .goodsOrderList li:last-child {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border-bottom: none; }
      .goodsOrderList li:last-child:after {
        display: none;
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-212px, 0);
                transform: translate(-212px, 0);
        border-bottom: 2px solid #F7F9FA; }
        @media (min-width: 1200px) {
          .goodsOrderList li:last-child:after {
            display: block;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-148px, 0);
                    transform: translate(-148px, 0); } }
        @media (min-width: 1695px) {
          .goodsOrderList li:last-child:after {
            -webkit-transform: translate(-212px, 0);
                    transform: translate(-212px, 0); } }

.goodsOrderWrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F7F9FA;
  padding-top: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  background: #FFFFFF; }
  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    .goodsOrderWrap {
      width: 100%;
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 0; } }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .goodsOrderWrap {
      margin-left: 20px; } }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .goodsOrderWrap {
      margin-left: 0; } }

.goodsOrderImg {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 116px;
  height: 116px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px; }
  .goodsOrderImg img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto; }
  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    .goodsOrderImg {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      margin-left: 0; } }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .goodsOrderImg {
      width: 24%; } }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .goodsOrderImg {
      width: 158px; } }

.goodsOrderText {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 95%;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: "Panton Bold";
  line-height: 29px;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  color: #3B3B3B; }
  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    .goodsOrderText {
      width: 80%;
      margin-left: 28px;
      vertical-align: middle; } }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .goodsOrderText {
      width: 80%;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      margin-top: 0px; } }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .goodsOrderText {
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 80%;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      margin-top: 0px; } }
  @media (min-width: 1695px) {
    .goodsOrderText {
      width: 30%;
      margin-bottom: 0; } }

.goodsOrderPrice {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 10px; }
  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    .goodsOrderPrice {
      width: 40%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      margin-left: 55px;
      margin-bottom: 0; } }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .goodsOrderPrice {
      position: relative;
      width: 35%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      margin-left: 55px; } }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .goodsOrderPrice {
      position: relative;
      width: 35%;
      top: 0;
      margin-left: 55px; } }
  @media (min-width: 1695px) {
    .goodsOrderPrice {
      position: relative;
      margin-left: 65px;
      width: 32%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0; } }

.goodsOrderPriceCount, .goodsOrderPriceRub {
  font-family: "Panton Bold";
  line-height: 29px;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  color: #3B3B3B; }

.goodsOrderPriceSum {
  display: block;
  ffont-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 23px;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  color: #3B3B3B; }

.goodsOrderPriceSumCount {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #3B3B3B; }


.goodsOrderBlock-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 40px; }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .goodsOrderBlock-wrap {
      margin-bottom: 43px; } }
  .goodsOrderBlock-wrap label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    line-height: normal;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    color: #4F4F4F !important; }

.goodsOrderBlock__title {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-family: "Panton Bold";
  line-height: 39px;
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;
  color: #4F4F4F; }

.goodsOrderBlock-input-wrap {
  position: relative; }

.goodsOrderBlock-input-item:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: url("../img/svg-static/search_icon_small.svg");
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 40px;
  right: 10px; }

.goodsOrderBlock-input {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em; }
  .goodsOrderBlock-input:hover {
    transition: .6s;
    border: 1px solid #80BAB6; }
  .goodsOrderBlock-input:focus {
    border: 1px solid #80BAB6; }

.goodsOrderBlock__delivery-wrap, .goodsOrderBlock__payment-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px; }

.goodsOrderBlock-choice_list {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px; }
  .goodsOrderBlock-choice_list li {
    display: inline-block; }

.goodsOrderBlock-choice_item {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 230px;
  height: 110px;
  background: #F7F9FA;
  border: 3px solid transparent; }
  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    .goodsOrderBlock-choice_item {
      width: 368px; } }
  .goodsOrderBlock-choice_item:hover, .goodsOrderBlock-choice_item:active, .goodsOrderBlock-choice_item:focus {
    z-index: 1;
    transition: .6s;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 3px solid #56A59E;
    box-shadow: 0px 45px 85px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); }

.goodsOrderBlock-choice_item-delivery--act, .goodsOrderBlock-choice_item-payment--act {
  background: #FFF;
  border: 3px solid #56A59E !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 45px 85px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  z-index: 1; }

.goodsOrderBlock-choice_item-inner {
  display: table;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }

.goodsOrderBlock-choice_item-img {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30%;
  vertical-align: middle; }

.goodsOrderBlock-choice_item-img__img1 {
  background: url("../img/svg-sprites/sprite.svg") no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 11.267605633802816%;
  width: 58px;
  height: 63px; }

.goodsOrderBlock-choice_item-img__img2 {
  background: url("../img/svg-sprites/sprite.svg") no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 22.202797202797203%;
  width: 59px;
  height: 59px; }

.goodsOrderBlock-choice_item-img__img3 {
  background: url("../img/svg-sprites/sprite.svg") no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 32.804232804232804%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 64px; }

.goodsOrderBlock-choice_item-text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 23px;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  color: #4F4F4F; }
  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    .goodsOrderBlock-choice_item-text {
      padding-left: 0; } }

.goodsOrderBlock-inf_block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #A6ADC0;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-left: 26px;
  padding-right: 26px;
  padding-bottom: 21px; }
  .goodsOrderBlock-inf_block:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    content: "";
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    border-left: 2px solid #A6ADC0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #A6ADC0; }
  .goodsOrderBlock-inf_block:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-22px, -10px) rotate(45deg);
            transform: translate(-22px, -10px) rotate(45deg);
    content: "";
    width: 37px;
    height: 26px;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #A6ADC0; }

.goodsOrderBlock-inf_block-left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: 20px; }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .goodsOrderBlock-inf_block-left {
      width: 45%;
      margin-bottom: 0; } }

.goodsOrderBlock-inf_block-right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  vertical-align: top; }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .goodsOrderBlock-inf_block-right {
      width: 50%;
      margin-left: 15px; } }

.goodsOrderBlock-inf_block__title {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 23px;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  color: #747B8E; }

.goodsOrderBlock-inf_block__list {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }
  .goodsOrderBlock-inf_block__list li {
    display: block;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 23px;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    color: #747B8E; }

.goodsOrderBlock-btn {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px; }

.goodsOrderBlock-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  color: #E0E0E0; }

.goodsOrderBlock-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  color: #E0E0E0; }

.goodsOrderBlock-input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  color: #E0E0E0; }

.goodsOrderBlock-input::placeholder {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  color: #E0E0E0; }

.goodsOrderItemsWrap--lk {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px; }
  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    .goodsOrderItemsWrap--lk {
      margin-bottom: 40px; } }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .goodsOrderItemsWrap--lk {
      margin-bottom: 40px; } }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .goodsOrderItemsWrap--lk {
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 60px; } }

.goodsOrderWrap--lk {
  width: 280px; }
  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    .goodsOrderWrap--lk {
      width: 100%; } }
  .goodsOrderWrap--lk:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 100%;
    left: -26px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #F7F9FA; }
    @media (min-width: 576px) {
      .goodsOrderWrap--lk:after {
        left: -26px; } }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .goodsOrderWrap--lk:after {
        left: -26px; } }
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      .goodsOrderWrap--lk:after {
        left: -26px; } }
    @media (min-width: 1695px) {
      .goodsOrderWrap--lk:after {
        left: -62px; } }

.goodsOrderList--lk li:last-child:after {
  display: none; }

.goodsOrderPrice--lk {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35%;
  position: relative;
  left: 14%;
  top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0; }
  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    .goodsOrderPrice--lk {
      left: 29%;
      width: 25%; } }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .goodsOrderPrice--lk {
      position: absolute;
      width: 20%;
      left: 455px;
      top: 66%; } }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .goodsOrderPrice--lk {
      width: 14%;
      left: 70%; } }
  @media (min-width: 1695px) {
    .goodsOrderPrice--lk {
      position: relative;
      width: 14%;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      vertical-align: middle; } }

.goodsOrderImg--lk {
  margin-bottom: 15px; }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .goodsOrderImg--lk {
      margin-bottom: 0; } }

.goodsOrderText--lk {
  display: block;
  width: 95%;
  margin-bottom: 10px; }
  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    .goodsOrderText--lk {
      width: 90%; } }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .goodsOrderText--lk {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 65%;
      margin-bottom: 0; } }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .goodsOrderText--lk {
      width: 65%; } }
  @media (min-width: 1695px) {
    .goodsOrderText--lk {
      width: 34%; } }

.goodsOrder-inner {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%; }
  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    .goodsOrder-inner {
      width: 74%; } }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .goodsOrder-inner {
      width: 74%; } }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .goodsOrder-inner {
      width: 74%; } }
  @media (min-width: 1695px) {
    .goodsOrder-inner {
      /*width: 82%;*/ } }

.goodsOrder-right {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; }
  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    .goodsOrder-right {
      width: 100%; } }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .goodsOrder-right {
      width: 90%; } }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .goodsOrder-right {
      width: 95%; } }
  @media (min-width: 1695px) {
    .goodsOrder-right {
      width: 65%; } }
```

```html
<div class="goodsOrder goodsOrderWrap js-goodsOrder cardClose cardClose386">
        <div class="goodsOrderImg">
                   <img src="/local/templates/onion_shop/img/empty.png" alt="image">
                 </div>
        <div class="goodsOrder-inner">
         <div class="goodsOrderText">
            Салфетки ONION 30х30см спанлейс 40гр/м2 БЕЛЫЕ 100шт/упак         </div>
         
         <div class="goodsOrder-right">
          <div class="goodsCounter goodsCounterWrap js-goodsCounter">
           <button class="goodsCounterLeft js-goodsCounterLeft" data-id="386" data-prcard="inputPrCard1" data-localsum="localSum1" data-localres="localRes1"><span>-</span></button>
           <button class="goodsCounterRight js-goodsCounterRight" data-id="386" data-prcard="inputPrCard1" data-localsum="localSum1" data-localres="localRes1"><span>+</span></button>
           <input class="inputPrCard1 cardActive1 dds_basket_quantity-386" data-action="updatebasket" data-order="Y" data-id="386" data-localsum="localSum1" data-localres="localRes1" type="text" value="1">
          </div>

          <div class="goodsOrderPrice ">
           <span class="goodsOrderPriceCount js-goodsOrderPriceCount localSum1">185</span>
           <span class="goodsOrderPriceRub">₽</span>
           <div class="goodsOrderPriceSum">
            <span>Итого</span> 
            <pre style="display:none">                        </pre>
            <span class="goodsOrderPriceSumCount localRes1">185</span>
            <span class="goodsOrderPriceSumCountRub">₽</span>
           </div>
          </div>

         </div>         
        
        </div>
        <button class="goodsOrderBtn btnClose js-goodsOrderBtn" data-id="386" data-action="delete" data-cardclose="cardClose386" data-cardactive="cardActive1"></button>
       </div>
```

*текст курсивом*

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте условие для события по клику click change submit - через if -> если input.val не равен пустому значению, то выполнение (ajax), если нет - то ничего либо вывод напоминания о введении инфо.